# How to hide element on small screens with Bootstrap 4 Beta

Tags: bootstrap-4

I just moved from bootstrap 4 alpha to beta, but I can't figure out how to hide an element on a small screen now. In the alpha this was "hidden-md-up" and "hidden-sm-down" which worked beautifully. "hidden-md-up" is now "d-md-none", but the other one I can't get to work

```
<div class="d-md-block d-xs-none d-sm-none">Show on large screen only - NOT working for me</div>
<div class="d-md-none">Show on small screen only</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A short break, cup of coffee later I figured it out: Adding the class "d-none d-md-block" will do the trick

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block">Show on large screen only works now</div>
<div class="d-md-none">Show on small screen only</div>
```

Read more about responsive display utilities at the [Bootstrap 4 Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/).

Comment: Answering your own question is not only acceptable but encouraged on Stack Overflow.  It is not important who answers the question, just that the answer is correct and properly explained.  However your silly joke/question about everyone hating people that answer their own questions should be left out.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The official documentation makes no mention of how the new way works compared to the old. I am actually still kind of lost as to why d-md-none is the same as hidden-md-up(which made sense to me) and how d-none and d-md-block need to be used together and what d-none and the block in d-md-block means in this context.

Comment: I agree, version 3 was more intuitive. The class names made sense to what you wanted to do.

Comment: @Kian I'll try to explain. Since bootstrap [4] is "mobile-first", you start there. So the question is, "do you want to show this on XS breakpoint?" If yes, no d-* classes needed as it will be shown on XS and all sizes bigger. If no, then do d-none. When you move to the next breakpoint [SM], ask yourself, "do I want to show this on SM breakpoint?". If yes and it's show for XS too, then no changes. If yes and XS was hidden (with d-none), then you need to do "d-sm-block". Rinse-repeat for each breakpoint that is bigger where the display property is different than the previous/smaller breakpoint

Answer (score 9):

I'm only adding this as an answer because it got too long for the comment...which was a reply to @Kian.

Since `bootstrap` [4] is "mobile-first", you start there.

So the question is, "do you want to show this on XS breakpoint?":

- If yes, no d-* classes needed as it will be shown on XS and all sizes
  bigger.
- If no, then do `d-none`.

When you move to the next breakpoint [SM], ask yourself, "do I want to show this on SM breakpoint?".

- If yes and it's show for XS too, then no changes.
- If yes and XS was hidden (with `d-none`), then you need to do
  `d-sm-block`.
- If no and XS was shown, then do `d-sm-none`.
- If no and XS was hidden, then no changes.

Rinse-repeat for each `breakpoint` that is bigger where the display property is different than the previous/smaller `breakpoint`

Here are some examples:

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block">Show on medium, and bigger, screen sizes</div>
<div class="d-md-none">Show on extra small and small screen sizes</div>
<div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">Show on ONLY medium screen sizes</div>
<div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none d-xl-block">Show on ONLY small and extra large screen sizes</div>
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andegre/aq9Laaew/63496/)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use the d-propeties to show diffentes logos in differents breakpoint, I tried d-none d-*-block" , but it didn't work, only works d-none-*. Then I realized that I was appling the class to the .img. So you can use d-none-* (hide) to any element, but to display element d-*-block only work in a wrapper element like div.
I hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 5, you can use this to make it easier to find out what bootstrap size you are working:

```
<div style="display:block;text-align:center;">
    Grid: 
    <span class="d-none d-inline d-sm-none">XS</span>
    <span class="d-none d-sm-inline d-md-none">SM</span>
    <span class="d-none d-md-inline d-lg-none">MD</span>
    <span class="d-none d-lg-inline d-xl-none">LG</span>
    <span class="d-none d-xl-inline d-xxl-none">XL</span>
    <span class="d-none d-xxl-inline">XXL</span>

</div>
```

this will show the current size (xs/sm/md/lg/xl/xxl) and hide the rest